# Python while loop, pause while not, continue again when true?

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi, gpio

Here is a bit of python I'm borrowing. Its on a raspberry pi monitoring three pins with reed switches on doors. If the door opens it says "door open".

The problem is that it keeps repeating open. I want it say it once, pause, to wait till the door closes and resume monitoring.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as io
import subprocess
io.setmode(io.BCM)

#pir_pin = 18
door_pin = 24
door_pin2 = 4
door_pin3 = 22
#io.setup(pir_pin, io.IN)         # activate input
io.setup(door_pin, io.IN, pull_up_down=io.PUD_UP)  # activate i$
io.setup(door_pin2, io.IN, pull_up_down=io.PUD_UP)  # activate $
io.setup(door_pin3, io.IN, pull_up_down=io.PUD_UP)  # activate $


while True:
   # if io.input(pir_pin):
    #    print("PIR ALARM!")
    if io.input(door_pin):
        print("DOOR Open!")
    if io.input(door_pin2):
        print("DOOR Open2!")
    if io.input(door_pin3):
        print("DOOR open3!")
        subprocess.call(['/usr/sipcmd-master/doording.sh'])
    time.sleep(1.9)
```

I tried the bottom lines, but apparently I can't use a true condition in a true condition?

edit: maybe a simplified version of my question, how can I make a loop wait for a change before continue. i.e. wait while pin = 0, do X when pin = 1

Comment: You missed a `:` on `if True`. Also, `if True: continue` will make the loop always skip the call to `time.sleep()`. If you want to check the door every so often, take the check out of its loop, make it a function, then use [Cron](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md) to schedule the check. If you want something to happen every time the door opens or closes, bind a callback to the event (not sure how to do that in Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Fixed the : but it still doesn't do what I want. I want the loop to wait' or 'pause' until the door is closed and then resume.

Comment: The only thing that `time.sleep()` can pause until is the passing of a specified time interval. On top of that, it sounds like you're not clear on the meaning of `if True` or `continue`. `if True` checks if `True` evaluates to `True`, which it always does, so that branch is always entered. `continue` immediately goes back to reevaluate the loop condition instead of executing the rest of the loop. What you're looking for is binding a callback to the opening and closing events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should put an intentional infinite loop in there to poll for the door being closed:

```
while True:
    if io.input(door_pin):
        print("DOOR Open!")
        while io.input(door_pin):
            pass # do nothing - the door is still open
    # now continue doing whatever you want after the door is closed again
```

I know this doesn't really "pause" the application, because it will still consume resources while the polling loop spins. But I assume you're okay with that since you're polling for the doors to be opened too.

Comment: I think that polling for the doors to be open is simply a mistake, and the presence of one mistake doesn't mean it's okay to add more. It's like giving an answer that masks `int` because the asker's code masks `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What makes you think the open door polling was a mistake? The OP wrote an infinite loop to check for open doors repeatedly, and just wants the script to wait while one is open. That looks pretty intentional to me. And even if it was a mistake, handling asynchronous events in Python is a HUGE step up in complexity, so I think this is a perfectly fine solution as long as the OP is aware that it still consumes resources, which I pointed out. It certainly isn't as bad as suggesting he/she use a variable name that masks a built-in.

Comment: This is an XY problem: the asker is trying to act on user events (problem X), has decided to use an infinite loop (consuming 100% CPU all the time - and remember, the Raspberry Pi is a small device that may be running on a battery), and is now asking how to make the infinite loop work properly (problem Y). I would be very surprised if Raspberry Pi doesn't have a decent API for event callbacks.

Comment: if someone wants to write an elegant solution I'd be grateful, but in lieu of that I'll take this. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this module](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) and the threaded callback. If nothing else, change the `pass` to `time.sleep(0.1)` which, though it won't make your module more responsive, will at least allow other programs to use the CPU.